# Get the value of month and year on credit card expiry date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, github

I am copy the code from this [**Link**](https://github.com/CardJs/CardJs)

I want to get value of month and year when user enter a expire date. I am applying with **onKeyPress** and **onKeyUp** but I cannot get any value in it

```
<!-- Card expiry (element that is displayed) -->
  <input class="expiry form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>

  <!-- Card expiry - Month (hidden) -->
  <input  class="expiry-month exp" name="card_exp_month" id="card_exp_month" required onKeyPress="edValueKeyPress()" onKeyUp="edValueKeyPress()">

  <!-- Card expiry - Year (hidden) -->
  <input class="expiry-year exp" name="card_exp_year" id="card_exp_year"  required>
```

Script code

```
function edValueKeyPress()
{
    var card_exp_month = document.getElementById("card_exp_month").value();
    alert(card_exp_month);

    var card_exp_year = document.getElementById("card_exp_year").value();
    alert(card_exp_year);
}
```

what is the right way to get value of month and year from https://github.com/CardJs/CardJs

Comment: you should use .value() along with document.getElementById()

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt - `value` isn't a function.

Comment: still not getting value

Comment: @Arslan - It works jsut fine if you use `value` correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/zn0da9k4/ Also note you'll want to add handlers to the year field, and you're better off with the `input` event, not key-related ones (think: pasting with the mouse). Recommend deleting the question, and making good use of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model.

Comment: @ T.J Crowder are you check this link https://github.com/CardJs/CardJs  ? I am working from this code which mention in link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `value`is not as function. Just remove the parenthesis and it should work.

```js
function edValueKeyPress()
{
    var card_exp_month = document.getElementById("card_exp_month").value;
    console.log(card_exp_month);

    var card_exp_year = document.getElementById("card_exp_year").value;
    console.log(card_exp_year);
}
```

```html
<!-- Card expiry (element that is displayed) -->
  <input class="expiry form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>

  <!-- Card expiry - Month (hidden) -->
  <input  class="expiry-month exp" name="card_exp_month" id="card_exp_month" required onKeyPress="edValueKeyPress()" onKeyUp="edValueKeyPress()">

  <!-- Card expiry - Year (hidden) -->
  <input class="expiry-year exp" name="card_exp_year" id="card_exp_year"  required>
```

By the way, using `onKeyPress` and `onKeyUp` is not a good idea IMHO, it will be triggered too many times. You'd maybe better use onChange or a submit button... Well it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Write separate onKeyPress functions for month and year. And .value is needed to get any input's value not value(). The code should be: var card_exp_month = document.getElementById("card_exp_month").value;